# Iterate one for in loop through multiple objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, loops, iteration, for-in-loop

I have two JSON object `obj1` & `obj2`. I want to compare values of these objects.

```
var obj1 = {"Don":"Test1","is":"hey","here":"yeah"};
var obj2 = {"Don":"Test1","is":"20","here":"lol"};
```

I want to do something like this:

```
for( var key1 in obj1 && var key2 in obj2){
  if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(key1) && obj2.hasOwnProperty(key2))
    console.log(obj1[key1]+ " : " + obj2[key2]);
}
```

My output should be:

```
Test1:Test1
hey:20
yeah:lol
```

Comment: You need a nested loop

Comment: `obj2.hasOwnProperty(key2)`

Comment: @Johan but how can I compare respective values of key for both?
I want to iterate both object at same time so that respective values can be compared.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the keys (`Object.keys` returns only enumerable properties):

```
var obj1 = {"Don":"Test1","is":"hey","here":"yeah"};
var obj2 = {"Don":"Test1","is":"20","here":"lol"};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach( function (key) { console.log(obj1[key]+':'+obj2[key]); } );
```

[**See also ...**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)